# * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

This problem arises when I installed  "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
"react-native-video-controls": "^2.8.1" these two dependencies . If I try  to run this on android it is showing this weird error * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - file:/C:/Users/hp/.m2/repository/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - file:/C:/Users/hp/MovieApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - file:/C:/Users/hp/MovieApp/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - https://www.jitpack.io/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-video

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2468#issuecomment-913709636)?